# How do I make the country field unrequired?

Tags: magento-1.9, dropdown-attribute

In the addressbook I already made the telephone field unrequired by setting the field `is_required` to `0` for attribute with the `attribute_code` "telephone" in the `eva_attribute` table. I searched for an attribute with the attribute code "country" but I just found "country_id".

(Yea and I already copied the `abstract.php` into the local code folder and commented out the two `if`-s in the function `_basicCheck()`. And I removed the `class="required"` in `edit.phtml` and `shipping.phtml`)

The reason I want to make it not required is because it is blank and even when I found a solution and it showed countries and I pressed "Save Address" the error poped up that "Country is a required field". So a soltuion for making the country drop down work would also be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The address validation is done in `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::validate`.
You need to copy this class in the local folder (because you cannot rewrite it in a clean way) and remove the lines that validate the country

```
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getCountryId(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the country.');
    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you that you took the time to answer.

Comment: But I already did this. I copied /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php and pasted a copy in /magento/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address. And I commented out what you said. Any other ideas?

Comment: that's all I have. Sorry.